# Website down but server is fine

Tags: linux, domain

Apologies if this is a vague/if I've missed any information. One of my biggest websites are down and it's causing lots of problems. The server which it is hosted on is absolutely fine (all the other websites are loading perfectly) and I changed nothing when the domain, let's say example.com just suddenly wasn't accessible anymore.

I have contacted GoDaddy and they say the DNS is absolutely fine. I can access the website on a different hostname but when I go to example.com, I'm just seeing 'The webpage is not available'.

I've tried pinging the domain example.com from my local machine as well as the server it's hosted on but I just see 'unknown host'. I've also used remote services such as downforeveryoneorjustme.com and this says the website is just down for me. However, there are people in my town calling me telling me the website is down.

I am really out of ideas so any help would be VERY MUCH appreciated.

The server is Linux CentOS and I'm using Plesk control panel

**Update: I have just checked Twitter for "Godaddy DNS" and it's very much a Godaddy issue. Thank you very much for all your help. I guess it's time to move away from Godaddy..**

Comment: Yeah, [your DNS has issues](http://www.intodns.com/itemsofbeauty.co.uk)... No idea why GoDaddy would say that's "absolutely fine" as it clearly is not.

Comment: "one of my biggest websites"...."Godaddy"...."plesk": three phrases one should never see in the same post.

Answer (score 3):

We have same issues, it most certainly is an issue with the dns servers from godaddy: http://www.intodns.com/itemsofbeauty.co.uk

Update: GoDaddy is aware: http://support.godaddy.com/system-alerts/

Comment: I have just checked Twitter for "Godaddy DNS" and it's very much a Godaddy issue. Thank you very much for all your help. I guess it's time to move away from Godaddy..

Answer (score 2):

The authoritative DNS servers `ns53.domaincontrol.com.` and `ns54.domaincontrol.com.` are currently not responding to requests sent over IPv4 (to `216.69.185.27` and `208.109.255.27`).

They are however still responding to requests sent over IPv6 (to `2607:f208:206::1b` and `2607:f208:302::1b`).

This means IPv4 only DNS servers will not be able to resolve your domain.

The authoritative DNS servers for `domaincontrol.com.` only have glue for IPv4, which means IPv6 only DNS servers will not be able to resolve your domain.

The outcome of this is that currently your domain can only be resolved by dual stack DNS servers. Some DNS servers may have cached records, and will be able to resolve it until the cached records expire.

Comment: Oh, so that's why it worked for me but not many other people. I have IPv6.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I wonder when redundancy becomes a major selling point for dual stack. This is not the first time I see an outage affecting only one of the protocols.